# Firefox OS privileged app won't let me load JWPlayer

Tags: firefox, firefox-os

I have a simple application developed for Firefox OS. It only loads the video player for now, I'm using JWPlayer CDN library for it.

I need to add more features in it, in order to do so I need to keep the type as privileged in manifest.webapp :

```
"type": "privileged",
```

However, as soon as I define it, JWPlayer stops working. It only works with web as type.

I've also tried following but no luck:

```
"installs_allowed_from": [
         "*"
],
```

Any solutions ?